# Do astronauts get co-authorship for experiments they conduct in space?

Tags: authorship

Astronauts aboard the ISS help perform plenty of experiments during their flight. Do they get listed as co-authors for the research they help conduct?

Comment: Similarly, are lab technicians on earth usually listed as co-authors?

Comment: @GEdgar In some fields lab technicians contribute _a lot_ to an experiment and so, yes, we list them as coauthors.

Comment: I guess a related question is: do astronauts still care about co-authorship once they've had the chance to go into space? I can imagine that one going either way: on the one hand, most people want to be rewarded for the contributions they make, regardless of anything else they're doing; on the other hand, you might expect going into space to trump getting another paper published.

Answer (score 15):

[Here](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/results_category) is a page collecting research performed on the ISS, with citations to published papers.  And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_crew) is a list of ISS crew.  The first few papers I checked from the [2015-16 report](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss_annual_results_highlights_2017_singlepage_11-9-17.pdf) didn't have any crew members among their authors.

This seems reasonable to me.  Normally authorship is based on making an *intellectual* contribution to the project: designing experiments, analyzing data, and so on.  I wouldn't particularly expect the astronauts to be involved that way - I'd assume they are mainly just carrying out the procedures designed by other researchers.  It's an important role, obviously, but it's not what authorship is intended to recognize.

Answer (score 6):

This is an anecdotal non-answer to a somewhat different question, but I know of [one scholarly paper](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/special/) that was authored by an astronaut, Michael Foale, in connection with his experiences aboard the Mir Space Station in 1997.

The full (and quite fascinating) story that led to the publication of this paper is told [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/right-spin-how-fly-broken-space-craft) and [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/special/transcript/html/) (and, most memorably in my opinion, [here](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos/special-productions-events/the-right-spin); sadly this excellent video is not freely available online, which is a pity because I play it for my students every time I teach a calculus class and they find it pretty inspiring, which suggests that other math instructors could benefit from doing that as well).

Comment: That's strange that the video isn't freely available online -- The AMS says on [this website](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/msamhome/05-dvd.html) that "A limited number of complimentary copies of The Right Spin are available upon request at [e-mail address]". I wonder why they'd give a couple away, but not make the content freely available...